# Assign a list of movie to an user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm totaly new in all database stuff. What I would like to do is save a list of movies that belongs to a user. For exemple the user "james" likes the following movies "james bond, matrix, the revenant, batman". I don't know how to assign this list of movies to the user "james", I don't know how to create my tables and fields for that. If you could give me an hint, I would apreciate.

Thanks

Comment: See normalisation within any basic introduction to sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user table

```
     id   |   user   |   other    |   email
```

movie table

```
    id   |   name   |    year    |   etc
```

user_movie (this is called a pivot table)

```
    user_id  |   movie_id
```

pivot tables are fairly amazing.
example

```
users 
id   |   name    |   details
3    |   Hakim   |   xxxxxxx
4    | Mohammed  |   xxxxxxx

videos
id   |    name   |   year
2    |    matrix |  2000
3    |  Batman R.|  2008
4    | deadpool  | 2016
5    | Minions   | 2015

user_video (pivot table)
user_id    |    video_id
  3        |     3
  3        |     5
  4        |     2
  4        |     3
  4        |     4
```

this way one users can watch many videos, and vice versa.
:)

Answer (score 1):

link the user id with the movie id
It can be a third table PK, userid, movieid,

Answer (score 1):

You're saying movie and user have a many-to-many relation. To express this in a relational database you need a linking table. Depending on your DBMS, the SQL create table statements will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
  NUMBER id PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXT name
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  NUMBER id PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXT name  
);

CREATE TABLE user_movie(
  NUMBER movie_id REFERENCES movie(id),
  NUMBER user_id REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about SQL commends, you can find fast and simple help over here [MySQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/index.php)
Now you need [CREATE TABLE](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/tables/create_table.php) (with fields...)
You need 3 tables to do that right, for example: users, movies and user_movies
go.
good luck!